# Pass parameter from AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a text field and AJAX function to find required string for search.
The way it works is like this, a user will enter search identifier in the search field.
Then AJAX function is performed to find relevant string for search.

```
  function Get_Search_Params() {
    
    //This is search field where user enter identifier
    var search_value = $('#SNOW_INC').val();

    $.ajax({
      url : "get_snow_params.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { search_value : search_value } ,

        success : function(data, status){
          $('#GetDetails').html(data);
        }
      });
  }
```

The return data is what I intend to use as search string.

```
  function Search_INC() {
    
  // what to pass here

    $.ajax({
      url : "find_snow_inc.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { ???: ???} ,

        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#INCRecords').empty();
          $("#INCloader").show();
        },
        complete: function(){
          $("#INCloader").hide();
        },

        success : function(data, status){
          $('#INCRecords').html(data);
        }
      });
  }
```

Or is there a better way to handle this request?
All I want is user to enter a string like ABC123 then it searches the DB, it then returns a string like *User unable to print*. (I got this far)
I need the string *User unable to print* to be passed in function `Search_INC`.

Please advice, and thank you!!

Comment: So you want to pass the response data to Search_INC function?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

I did as per below and I could get what I want.

```
  function Get_Search_Params() {
    var search_value = $('#SNOW_INC').val();

    $.ajax({
      url : "get_snow_params.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { search_value : search_value } ,

        success : function(data, status){
          $('#GetDetails').html(data);
          Desc_BS_CI = data;
          Search_INC();
        }
      });
  }


//AJAX function to return incident results
  function Search_INC() {
    var search_value = $('#SNOW_INC').val();

    $.ajax({
      url : "find_snow_inc.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { Desc_BS_CI : Desc_BS_CI } ,

        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#INCRecords').empty();
          $("#INCloader").show();
        },
        complete: function(){
          $("#INCloader").hide();
        },

        success : function(data, status){
          $('#INCRecords').html(data);

        }
      });
  }
```

Let this help other :)